# query_posts -> get page_id from custom field

Tags: custom-field, query-posts

I'm customizing a page template and having an issue with getting a page id from a custom field.

The value of the custom field contains the page ID whose contents are to be called.

For a normal page I would do it like this:

```
<?php query_posts('page_id=155'); global $more; $more = 1;  ?>
```

But how do I get the value of the custom field as page ID for the query?

Thanks in advance

Totti

Answer (score 0):

You get a custom field by using get_post_meta:

```
<?php $pageID = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_field_name', true ); ?>
```

You can then use that for the query you need, but you should not use query_posts, this function overrides the main query and isn't normally used on themes or plugins, it should be avoided. This can increase page loading times and it's generally better to use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action (in case you want to change the main query).

You can also use [get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) if you just need to get the page data:

```
<?php $page = get_post( $pageID ); ?>
```

Comment: Never use `query_posts()`, it is very bad, even worst in a template file. Use `WP_Query` instead.

Comment: yes, you're right, I edited the message to reinforce that message